# How to verify if target=_blank worked in Android webview

Tags: android, jquery, html, webview

There is an Android app which uses HTML content within a WebView. Now, this HTML content contains a `target=_blank` link. Sometimes it works, but sometimes it gets blocked (i.e. link opens in same window), for unknown reasons.

```
<!-- Does not always work in WebView -->
<a id="link" href="http://example.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

```js
$('#link').click(function() {
   // if (linkOpenedInNewBrowserWindow.wasSuccessful)
   // Do something
});
```

How is it possible to check whether a click on this link actually opens the link in a new browser window or not?

Comment: I tried using `window.open` instead, but this was always blocked in a WebView, so I switched to using `target=_blank`

Comment: Bonus question: why does a `target=_blank` get blocked in an Android WebView anyway?